# How do I use XML class to show XML content in a gridview or listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, class

I got an XML file from online to use in my poject for school,this xml file is the one from kongregate for embedding games in my website.
the xml file is in ELEMENT format, but gridview and listview need it to be in ATTRIBUTE format.
This is the link for the xml file: http://www.kongregate.com/games_for_your_site.xml

I got a suggestion about turning it into a class, so I did, but i still dont know how to use it exactly.
This is the class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1
    /// </summary>


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class gameset
{

    private gamesetGame[] gameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("game")]
    public gamesetGame[] game
    {
        get
        {
            return this.gameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.gameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class gamesetGame
{

    private uint idField;

    private string titleField;

    private string thumbnailField;

    private System.DateTime launch_dateField;

    private string categoryField;

    private string featured_imageField;

    private string[] screenshotField;

    private string flash_fileField;

    private ushort widthField;

    private ushort heightField;

    private string urlField;

    private string descriptionField;

    private string instructionsField;

    private string developer_nameField;

    private uint gameplaysField;

    private decimal ratingField;

    private ushort id1Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    public uint id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string thumbnail
    {
        get
        {
            return this.thumbnailField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.thumbnailField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime launch_date
    {
        get
        {
            return this.launch_dateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.launch_dateField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string category
    {
        get
        {
            return this.categoryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.categoryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string featured_image
    {
        get
        {
            return this.featured_imageField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.featured_imageField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("screenshot")]
    public string[] screenshot
    {
        get
        {
            return this.screenshotField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.screenshotField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string flash_file
    {
        get
        {
            return this.flash_fileField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.flash_fileField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort width
    {
        get
        {
            return this.widthField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.widthField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort height
    {
        get
        {
            return this.heightField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.heightField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string url
    {
        get
        {
            return this.urlField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.urlField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string instructions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.instructionsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.instructionsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string developer_name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.developer_nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.developer_nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public uint gameplays
    {
        get
        {
            return this.gameplaysField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.gameplaysField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal rating
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ratingField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ratingField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("id")]
    public ushort id1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.id1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.id1Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Could you tell me how to show the data in ListView? Or could you convert my xml file from element to attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the fileds to properties and then after deserializing your xml file , you have a List then you just bind it to the listview
like any data.

```
 YourListView.DataSource = theListOfXmlItems;
 YourListView.DataBind();
```

you can find a simple tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by changing my class.
the class i had earlier is the one you get by using special copy xml to class.
i think the way i wrote it is what Thorarnis meant (changing the fields into properties)

this is the class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for GameXML
/// </summary>
[XmlRoot("gameset")]
public class GameSet
{
[XmlElement("game")]
public List<Game> Game { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("game")]
public class Game
{
[XmlElement("id")]
public int ID { get; set; }
[XmlElement("title")]
public string Title { get; set; }
[XmlElement("thumbnail")]
public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
[XmlElement("launch_date")]
public string Launch { get; set; }
[XmlElement("category")]
public string Category { get; set; }
[XmlElement("flash_file")]
public string Flash { get; set; }
[XmlElement("width")]
public string Width { get; set; }
[XmlElement("height")]
public string Height { get; set; }
[XmlElement("url")]
public string Url { get; set; }
[XmlElement("description")]
public string Description { get; set; }
[XmlElement("instructions")]
public string Instructions { get; set; }
[XmlElement("developer_name")]
public string Developer_name{ get; set; }
[XmlElement("gameplays")]
public string Gameplays { get; set; }
[XmlElement("rating")]
public string Rating { get; set; }


}
```